# Power Congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given $a$ and a modulo $m$, I'd like to ask how to calculate $x$ satisfying that $a^x \equiv x \pmod{m}$?

I notice that such $x$ always exists and can be the infinite tetration of $a$, meaning that $x \equiv a^{a^{a^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}} \ (mod \ m)$, but I'm not sure whether there are other solutions.

It also happens that this solution is the largest $x \lt m$ satisfying the equation.

Comment: It could be that the Chinese Remainder Theorem would help.

Comment: There might not be any such $x$. There might be several. What do you really want to do?

Comment: There may be something useful in https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10623-009-9339-2

Comment: OK, I guess you're not insisting on $0\le x\le m-1$.

Comment: The above only solves the subproblem where $m$ is a prime.

Comment: Yes. I'm also interested in the structure of solutions.

Comment: prime case solves a lot of others.

Comment: How are you so sure that x always exists? The infinite tetration of a is not a number, because it is infinite.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572221/conjecture-there-always-exist-k-in-bbb-n-such-that-mk-equiv-k-pmod-n-wh?noredirect=1&lq=1
I asked the same problem much earlier, but sadly I got a downvote.

Comment: @JeffHanks see the similar post above. Also, I have noticed the existence of the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}a^x\equiv x \bmod m&\implies a^x=my+x\\&\implies\nexists p\in \{p : p\mid x\} 
: \nexists b,\quad b^p\not\equiv x \bmod m\\&\implies\gcd(a,m)\mid x\end{align}$$

Any non-trivial shared factor, via the last one, makes this $0\equiv 0\bmod \gcd(a,m)$ boring.  If x is prime we get that a factors mod x .  Parity arguments show that if a and m are both odd, then x and y are opposite parity to each other.  Lastly, by associativity of multiplication, mod m can be restated into mod any given factor, including prime factors.