# Conjecture: There always exist $k\in \Bbb N$, such that $m^k\equiv k\pmod n$, where $m,n\in\Bbb N.$

Tags: number-theory, conjectures

### Conjecture:

> Let $m,n\in\Bbb N$. Then there always exists $k\in \Bbb N$, such that $m^k\equiv k\pmod n$ holds.

This question comes from [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4571935/1044391)

> Let $m,n\in\Bbb Z_{>0}$ are fixed numbers, such that $$m^{k_0}-k_0\equiv 0\pmod n$$ for some $k_0\in \Bbb N$.
> Then, there exist infinitely many $k$, such that $$m^k-k\equiv 0\pmod n.$$

We [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4572016/1044391) that, if there exist such $k$, then there exist infinitely many $k$.

> But here, the question is: Does there always exist the smallest $k$?

Numerical results support the conjecture. The question seems beyond of my elementary knowledge, so I don't have a non-trivial attempt, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the source of these problems?

Comment: Checked up to $n=656$

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24m%5Ek%5Cequiv%20k%5Cpmod%7Bn%7D%24&p=5), there's the quite similar [Power Congruence](/q/3272358), but it doesn't currently have any useful answer.

Comment: @DanielV No? If $m=0$ then take $k=n$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't have an exact source.  It was just due to an observation I made when dealing with a number theory problem.

Comment: Partial answer. If $n$ is a prime (say $p$), then there always exists a solution for $k$. In fact $m^{(p-1)^2}=1=(p-1)^2\mod p$

Comment: Search limit extended to $n=1\ 400$ , no counterexample.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for sharing this. Can you explain me the algorithm you wrote, please?

Comment: @User It is just a brute force algorithm, we can WLOG assume $m\le n$ , I have no idea of a useful improvement to accelerate the search.

Comment: Further extended to $n=2\ 000$ , no counterexample. I stop for now since the routine becomes quite slow in those ranges, but I might continue later. Perhaps anyone has an idea how to accelerate the search until then.

Comment: Please refrain from bumping the question with trivial edits.

Comment: @BillDubuque There was a deleted comment here.  That's why I edited my correctly written question incorrectly.  I corrected and rollback my question after MishaLavrov's comment.  I mentioned this in the summary section.

Comment: Cr. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3272358/power-congruence?noredirect=1#comment10243787_3272358

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a special case of the following fact:
**Claim:** Let $a,b,c$ be positive integers. Then there are infinitely many positive integers $x$ so that
$$a^x-x\equiv b\pmod c$$
This claim is similar to the following olympiad problem: [Brazil MO 2005/6](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h57713p354533),
in which $a^x-x$ is replaced by $a^x+x$. The link also contains a proof of that problem (in post #7). That proof works identically for this too. I'll sketch it for completeness.

We will prove the claim by induction on $c$, with base case $c=1$ trivial.
Now assume $c>1$. First, notice that the sequence $a, a^2, \dots$ is eventually periodic modulo $c$, say with period $\ell$. Let $d=\gcd(c,\ell)$.
We want to show that $d<c$. If not, we have $\ell=c$, which implies the sequence $a^i$ contains every residue mod $c$, so some power of $a$ is divisible by $c$, but in this case $\ell=1$ (the sequence is eventually constant).

Thus $d<c$. Then by the induction hypothesis, for every $0\leq i<d$ there is a large positive integer $n_i$ for which
$$a^{n_i}-n_i\equiv i \pmod d$$
By "large" I mean bigger than the last $i$ for which $a^i\not\equiv a^{i+\ell}\pmod c$.
Let $b=qd+r$, where $0\leq r<d$. Then we have
$$a^{n_r}-n_r=r+md$$
for some integer $m$. Because $n_r$ is large, we can write for any positive $y$:
$$a^{n_r+y\ell}-(n_r+y\ell)\equiv a^{n_r}-n_r-y\ell\equiv r+md-y\ell\pmod c$$
As $d=\gcd(c, \ell)$, we can find integers $A, B$ so that $Ac+B\ell=d$. Then picking $y\equiv mB\pmod c$ we get $a^x-x\equiv r\pmod c$ for $x=n_r+y\ell$, which finishes the proof.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a proof by strong induction on $n$ with $m$ fixed. In it I utilize your result that once such solution $k$ exists, then there are infinitely many solutions.

**Base case:**

Let $n=1$, then any $k$ works as $1$ is divisor of any integer.

**Induction step:**

Let $n>1$, and assume solution exists for all $i<n$. Let's write
$$n=ab,\gcd(a,m)=1,b \mid m^t$$
where $t$ is some sufficiently large positive integer.
This is just partitioning of prime factors of $n$ based on whether they divide $m$ or not. Now since $n>1$, we have $\varphi(a)\leq \varphi(n) <n$, and by the induction hypothesis there is $l$ such that
$$m^l\equiv l \pmod{\varphi(a)}.\tag{*}$$
By your result we know that since such solution exists, then infinitely many solutions exist. So choose $l$ such that $l\geq t$. Then $b\mid m^l$. Let $k=m^l$, we now show this $k$ satisfies $m^k\equiv k \pmod n$.

The $(*)$ implies $k\equiv l \pmod {\varphi(a)}$ and since $(a,m)=1$, Euler's theorem gives
$$m^{k-l}\equiv m^0=1 \pmod {a}.$$
So we have
$$
a\mid m^{k-l}-1,
b\mid m^l.
$$
But $ab=n$ and so
$$
n\mid m^l(m^{k-l}-1)=m^k-m^l=m^k-k
$$
which is just $m^k \equiv k \pmod {n}$, as required.
$\square$

**Note:** This appeared as a Problem 4 on [USA TST 2007](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4637_2007_usa_team_selection_test), you might find additional solutions there.